# solve the recurrence T(n)=T(2n/3)+n

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I don't know how to write math in here so i attached an image.
[image]

this is where I got using the iteration method for solving recurrences.

I'm not sure where to go from here but I know it's suppose to get to O(n). (assuming what I've done so far is correct)

I'd appreciate the solution using the same iteration method, and a correction if I did something wrong.

Comment: Not the same but [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116667/solving-tn-tn-2-t-n-3-n-with-recurrence-tree) is a similar question.

Comment: You did most of the work, you just need to use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The cool part of this problem, and why this case is not described by [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), is that there is no "split" - the `a` coefficient in `a T(n/b)` is 1, which leads to `c_crit = 0`, a degenerative case of the tree being more of a single stick.

Intuitively, this already means our degenerate tree is root heavy and that `n` from the topmost `T(n)` will dominate the result, leading to O(n) complexity.

A bit more formally, let's take it to extreme and assume our single stick tree is infinitely deep. So, in the right part, we'll use infinity instead of of `log_b a`. The sum of the infinite series will be `S = 1/(1-1/b) = 1/(1-2/3) = 3`.

We can be completely formal, compute an actual bound, and get a smaller coefficient - but in terms of complexity it won't change anything.

So, regardless of the "tree" depth, the overall complexity is going to be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The last term in your last equation represents the sum of the first few terms of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

∑<sup><sup>−</sup></sup><sub><sub>=</sub></sub><sup><sup>1</sup></sup><sub><sub>0</sub></sub> (2/3)

As (2/3) is less than 1, the sum converges. It converges to:

∑<sup><sup>∞</sup></sup><sub><sub>=0</sub></sub> (2/3) = (1 / (1 − 2/3)) = 3

As we don't take an *infinite* number of terms, but  terms, the coefficient of  will be less than 3, but that is irrelevant in big O terms.

So we end up with O().